# SharePoint Email Alert Triggered By User Actions

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction with this problem.

We have written a Farm Solution in Visual Studio that will create a subsite with various features.

When certain actions are performed by the user, we need a email to be sent to select users of that subsite.

The features and the actions that will cause emails to be sent out are:

- Announcement - creation of announcement
- Survey - survey is answered
- Document Library - document is edited or comment given
- Forum - user posts a post

We have been told that there's no way to write code to detect such actions, because it's not built into the system.

I am open to other suggestions.

One given to me is to use SharePoint Designer and create a workflow for email alerting, but the user would have to add
this in themselves for each feature, whereas we want the email alerting to be already present. Also we're not sure if the workflow can detect those actions as well.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two options:

1. you can make use of the 'alerts' functionality on lists. Each user
   can define alerts such as new item has been created, item has been
   modified, etc... They can even decide when the mail has to be sent
   (immediately, weekly, daily). As said, each user should enable this
   alert by themselve (bell icon in ribbon) but in my opinion a site
   collection admin can create them (eg. on a user group). You can also create those alerts through powershell (http://www.eblogin.com/eblogin/post/2011/11/23/creating-useralerts.aspx#.VwdWkr8nLug)
2. create a farm solution and make use of list event receivers to
   detect itemadding, itemupdating. Mailing can then be handled through
   c# (by reading in specific user groups, collecting the email
   adresses and sending the mail.

First option does not let you manipulate the title/body of the mail. In the second option you are free to send what you want